# Как с помощью CSS осуществить изменение высоты изображения в зависимости от высоты области просмотра

Tags: css

Как с помощью CSS сделать, чтобы на мониторе с разрешением 1024х768 высота изображений в статье на сайте была не более 768px, с разрешением 1440х900 - не более 900px и т.д.?

То есть, чтобы изображение по высоте не превышало высоту разрешения дисплея или высоту окна браузера?

Comment: `max-height: 100vh;`

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, да, это вроде бы работает. А я мучился с @media only screen

Answer (score 2):

Подходов и приёмов достаточно много:

1. [Медиа-запросы](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy) (Media queries) - это специальные условия для css, которые включают дополнительные стили при соблюдении внешних факторов. Например, для определённой ширины или высоты;
2. Задавать высоту в %. При этом придётся выстраивать DOM-дерево так, чтобы все родительские блоки тоже следовали этому правилу и не превышали высоту области просмотра. Это так называемая "резиновая" или "эластичная" вёрстка;
3. [Задавать высоту изображения в vh](https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/) - это как проценты, но считаются не от родителя, а от окна браузера;
4. Возможно, чем-то вам смогут помочь [flex-контейнеры](https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox). Там тоже много приёмов для тянущихся блоков.

Какой вариант выбрать - всё зависит от того, как именно выстроено ваше DOM-дерево. В любом из 4-ёх вариантов, вам может пригодиться свойство max-height.